How to draw text in Android like I drew it in WinForms?
I drew a text in both WinForms and Android on bitmap.
The text is: Καλώς ήρθατε στην επίσκεψη, then the font is Arial and then font size is 12.
In WinForms, I used graphics and set it to anti-alias.
In Android, I used canvas and paint, and they are also both set to anti-alias.
In WinForms (Zoomed):

In Android (Zoomed):

In WinForms, I set TextRenderingHint to AntiAliasGridFit and CompositingQuality to Default and SmoothingMode to None
in WinForm:
Bitmap _StringBitmap = new Bitmap(4096, 64); 

   

     Font _font = new Font("Arial",12);        
            SolidBrush _drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);            
            StringFormat _strFormat = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;      
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            int _rectHeight = _font.Height;                             
            Graphics _StrGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(_StringBitmap);          
            _StrGraphic.Clear(Color.Black);                        
            _StrGraphic.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
            _StrGraphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.Default;
            _StrGraphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
stringSize = _StrGraphic.MeasureString(str, _font, 4096, _strFormat);
_StrGraphic.DrawString(str, _font, Brushes.White, 
                                    new Rectangle(
                                        0,
                                        0, 
                                        Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(stringSize.Width)) + 1, 
                                        Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(stringSize.Height)) + 1),
                                    _strFormat);

in Android:
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(309, 36, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

Canvas canvas = new(bmp);

canvas.DrawColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
canvas.DrawFilter = new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, PaintFlags.AntiAlias | PaintFlags.FilterBitmap);

 Paint paint = new()
 {
     Color = Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"),
     AntiAlias = true
 };
 Typeface arail = Typeface.Create("Arial", TypefaceStyle.Normal);
 paint.SetTypeface(arail);
 paint.TextSize = 12;
 string str1 = str.Substring(start, len);

 paint.FilterBitmap = true;

 Rect rect1 = new();

 paint.GetTextBounds(str1, 0, str1.Length, rect1);

 canvas.DrawText(str1, 0, rect1.Height(), paint);

I also tried to copy windows Arial font with extension .ttf to android assets.
 arail = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/ARIALN.TTF");

but did not work.
Update:
I found the new font, which is Microsoft Sans Serif, which is the nearest similarity with:


First is the original image in Android, and
it is similar but still not the same.
So I wonder if it is GridFit that makes it
as from what @Dai said,

I suggest you set
AntiAlias = false;

and
paint.FilterBitmap = false;

– and remove the flags from
DrawFilter(0, PaintFlags.AntiAlias | PaintFlags.FilterBitmap);


but there's still a bit of a difference.

the W from Android 
compared with the W from WinForm 

Please [edit] your post and add the code you use. Without seeing it, all I can say is that that looks like a bitmap font, so perhaps you are not setting the font correctly?

@KenY-N thank you and I have updated it.

Looking at this question there might be hints about what to do; TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit might be better?

what I want is to draw like in winform and there is no TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit  in android right?

I'm not an Android developer, but what you want is to disable text anti-aliasing (and/or subpixel rendering), so I suggest you set AntiAlias = false and paint.FilterBitmap = false - and remove the flags from DrawFilter(0, PaintFlags.AntiAlias | PaintFlags.FilterBitmap); - and see what happens

what you said helpped me  a lot but there is a bit differece and I have upload it @Dai

In winform I set AntiAliasGridFit and why should I set antialise to false in android?

@newprogrammer, have you tested this

AntiAlias = false and paint.FilterBitmap = false - and remove the flags from DrawFilter(0, PaintFlags.AntiAlias | PaintFlags.FilterBitmap); from what you've updated in your question, and from what @Dai said?
